# How can I create an object of a class that can remain in memory and be accessible to all other classes?

Tags: java, android

I parse a html document and save the data in class. how can I access that class from different classes without initiating it again because I want to use one version of that class

Comment: Make the class a singleton, serialize it, or inject it into your other classes.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: Do you mean during the same runtime or are you trying to do this across multiple runs?

Comment: @UncleIroh "or inject it" isnt making it serializable and injecting it the same thing?

Comment: @user521180 - No, I believe Uncle Iroh is referring to [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: @user521180 - David is correct, I was referring to DI.  However singleton's do not require DI -- you could just reference the singleton instance. I should have just left my comment at "Make the class a singleton" instead of muddying the waters mentioning serialization or dependency injection.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you set it to a static variable?

public static HtmlData data;

private void parse() {
···
data = result;
}

// now you can use the data object anywhere in your code by calling HtmlData.data

Comment: the singleton would be a much better solution, as far as hes talking about holding holding it for this runtime. assumedly hes trying to hold many object in one class. also, having the variable public static and non final is bad practice.

Comment: If he needs it only for holding one object this is the way to go. About public variable, put a geter/seter around it. its much easier to implement. If he needs multiple objects, I agree with singleton, but not serialization. He can use a map or a list inside the singleton to hold the objects.

Answer (score 0):

As said in your comments, a singlton would be the way to go. A singleton is holding and managing its own instance, so that you can return this same instance to everyone asking for it.

catchword 'dependency injection', best practice, rather than calling the factory via static access directly, is holding the instance in a private property within the class you need it and "inject the dependency" with public setter in a centralized way, while initializing your application.